# how to in kibana filter a specific index

Tags: kibana

In kibana I have defined an index pattern that includes multiple indexes like this:
[image: integr* pattern]

I would like add a filter on field _index during visualization: [image: like this]

Could someone please help me?

When using the AND keyword, the following error is generated: [image: error with the "AND" operator].

Answer (score 0):

Your query syntax is wrong.  Using a `,` between expresssions is not correct.  You need to use `AND` (and it has to be capitalized).  For example: `_type:x AND _index:y`

Comment: I have tried it but in my case it doesn't work. I'm editing the post with a new image with the error.

Comment: the error when using a `_index:name*` should be obvious -- you can't do a prefix match on an index name field (ES limitation).  Note that to match your previous example, you'd use `_index:integr_prod`, not `_index:integr*`

Comment: see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html -- specificially: does not support prefix, wildcard, regexp, or fuzzy queries.

Comment: if you do need to do wildcard matching against the index name, just create a new index pattern that has the appropriate wildcard and use that as the source for the visualization instead of the original pattern